# What clipboard formats are supported by HTML5 drop targets?

Tags: javascript, windows, html, drag-and-drop

This list of clipboard formats refers:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx

I have created an HTML5 drop target on a page and played around by dragging data from various applications into it.

When I debug the Javascript, I can find data in the `event.dataTransfer` object for each. The only exception has been when dragging from a tree control in SAP GUI, which is what I am actually after. In that case, the `dataTransfer.item` list is empty, as is the .type list. Calling `dataTransfer.getData()` returns nothing.

I have tried this in IE, Chrome and Firefox with the same result.

My investigation in this has led me to believe that there is a limitation on the support for certain clipboard formats for HTML5. What formats are supported?

What I would like to be able to do is get at the clipboard contents (as shown below in the first update).

**UPDATE 2**

Below is the code of the page. I set breakpoints in the `drop()` function from where I can analyse the event object.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style> #drop_target {width: 350px; height: 70px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; } </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="drop_target"></div>
</body>
<script>

var drop_target   = document.getElementById('drop_target');

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(ev.dataTransfer.types.length);
  console.log(ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
}

drop_target.addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop, false);
drop_target.addEventListener('dragenter', allowDrop, false);
drop_target.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

</script>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1**

I found a nice utility from the Code Project called [ClipSpy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168/ClipSpy) which allows me to see the content of the drag event, and it looks like this:

[image]

Compare that to something like the following, when dragging a piece of text from my browser:

[image]

I guess the question now becomes more along the lines of: How can I access the raw drag event data in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

After looking some more at the W3 spec regarding "Clipboard API and events", I came across the following:

> **clipboardData**
>
> The clipboardData attribute is an instance of the
>   DataTransfer interface which lets a script read and manipulate values
>   on the system clipboard during user-initiated copy, cut and paste
>   operations. *The associated drag data store is a live but filtered view*
>   of the system clipboard, exposing mandatory data types the
>   implementation knows the script can safely access. For synthetic
>   events, the drag data store contains the data added by the script that
>   created the event.

The "mandatory data types" it talks about links to here (in the same document):

https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#mandatory-data-types

Where there is a list of clipboard formats which are apparently supported (or meant to be supported by implementations of the spec).

In that case, I must conclude that custom clipboard formats are probably not supported.